# Como puedo acceder al string de nombrePescado

Tags: javascript, array, visual-studio, string, objeto

//Lo que necesito es poder acceder al string que esta dentro del array del asignacion nombre pescado.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola buenas, ¿qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Cómo es la estructura de tu objeto? Seguramente con el punto puedes acceder a la propiedad `nombrePescado` de tu pedido, y con corchetes y un índice podrías acceder al nombre del pescado. No veo el nombre de tu objeto `Pedido`, así que, si fuera `pedido`, sería `pedido.nombrePescado[0]`

Comment: Simplemente te puedo decir algo ERES UN CRACK, mil gracias